# dayjs isSameOrAfter method not working as expected

Tags: node.js, dayjs

```js
console.log(dayjs('2023-06-11T23:40:00.000Z').isSameOrAfter(dayjs('2023-06-12T13:40:00.000Z'), 'day'))
```

Based on my understanding of the `isSameOrAfter` method, it should return `false` when comparing the given dates since `'2023-06-11T23:40:00.000Z'` is not the same day nor after `'2023-06-12T13:40:00.000Z'`.

I would appreciate any insights into why this behavior is occurring and how I can resolve it

Comment: Have you tried it like this: `dayjs('2023-06-11T23:40:00.000Z').isSameOrAfter('2023-06-12T13:40:00.000Z', 'day')`? That is how I saw it in the [documentation](https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/is-same-or-after). Maybe using dayjs inside the function messes things up, since they use it internally (s. L.115-122 of [this](https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/b3624de619d6e734cd0ffdbbd3502185041c1b60/src/index.js#L115)).

Comment: it did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dayjs()` parses dates in local time, so if your local timezone is ahead of UTC the date will be `2023-06-12...`, if you want to parse it in UTC use [`dayjs().utc()`](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/utc) instead.

```js
console.log(dayjs('2023-06-11T23:40:00.000Z').format());

console.log(
  dayjs('2023-06-11T23:40:00.000Z').isSameOrAfter('2023-06-12T13:40:00.000Z', 'day')
)

console.log(
  dayjs.utc('2023-06-11T23:40:00.000Z').isSameOrAfter('2023-06-12T13:40:00.000Z', 'day')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.8/dayjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.8/plugin/utc.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.8/plugin/isSameOrAfter.js"></script>
<script>
  dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_utc);
  dayjs.extend(window.dayjs_plugin_isSameOrAfter);
</script>
```